# How to implement Materialized View in SAP HANA SP12

Tags: hana, materialized-views

How to implement Materialized View in SAP HANA?

Is it possible to create a materialize in SAP HANA SP12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific feature in SAP HANA that manages *materialized views*. Commonly, one would try to avoid such constructs as they are non-trivial to maintain and deal with.

One option to avoid a typical need for materialized views - query execution speed - is to use *cached views* in SAP HANA.

Another approach could be to implement your own query result storing/refreshing mechanism. Combined with functionality like *SAP HANA flowgraphs* this can be a viable alternative in certain setups.

Answer (score 0):

It does not exist on SAP HANA. Materialized Views purpose is not mainly for populating a table but have the feature for query rewrite and use prestored aggregates in very complex queries whtich are transparently redirectced to the aggregate but queried against the base source.